# Forward fill Nulls with last known value in group and forecast amounts with limits

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I'm a bit stuck trying to do forecasting using rolling avg windows functions across different groups. please see the example table below:

[image]

I've planned to do this across a few steps e.g.

1. Forward fill the null values with the last non-null in that group.

I've tried to do this but I'm coming unstuck with the code below as it doesn't forward fill using last just remains nulls:

```
SELECT *,
LAST_VALUE(Avg to Date per group) OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW  AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS filled_value
FROM table
ORDER BY group, date;
```

2. Create a new column 'forecast' that is a cumulative sum of the actuals to date per week per group and continue with the forward-filled nulls in 'Avg to date per group'
3. Limit the forecast col based on a value in another table. Update the last row with the correct amount to match the limit/cap

Would appreciate if someone could help with problem no 1 - filling nulls with the last known value and let me know if im on a half decent path to completing a forecast based on actuals or if I've got it very wrong!

Thanks again!

Comment: Perhaps you meant `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to this  [site](https://dbfiddle.uk) and construct a fiddle with your table and data - makes answering questions a lot easier and reduces the risk of error and eliminates duplication of effort on the part of those responding!